# Design Normal Form in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, database-design, normalization

I have 2 table (FirstTable & SecondTable). My FirstTable is header table and SecondTable is detail table, but FirstTable has complex primary key. How I can have a reference in my SecondTable to first Table that be NORMAL and best choice.

[image: Tables]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least three ways to do this in your case. The way you choose depends on information you haven't told us yet.

Think hard before you choose. The fact that you're asking such a very basic question suggests that you're likely to make mistakes in the implementation. (That's an observation, not a criticism.) Work on a scratch copy of your database first. Expect to destroy it.

1. Store the entire primary key of
   FirstTable in SecondTable. That
   means adding a column for Key_F2 in
   SecondTable, populating it with the
   right data, dropping the old
   constraint, and adding a new one,
   which will include a clause like
   `foreign key (Key_F1, Key_F2)
   references FirstTable (Key_F1,
   Key_F2)`.
2. Declare a UNIQUE constraint on
   FirstTable.Key_F1. Then you can add
   a new constraint to SecondTable
   which will include a clause like
   `foreign key (Key_F1) references
   FirstTable (Key_F1)`. Of course this
   will only work if values in
   FirstTable.Key_F1 are unique.
3. Add a column to SecondTable to store
   the value in FirstTable.ID, and
   populate that column with the right
   data. Then you can drop the column SecondTable.Key_F2, and set a foreign key
   reference from SecondTable.ID to
   FirstTable.ID.

Comment: thank you ver much. I thoght about No.3 and I want to konw if I use ID that is IDENTITY when I want to join First and Second table according ID is Optimizer use index of if ever? what is the best way according Normalization and Optimaization?

Comment: You can use IDENTITY in FirstTable. (Not in SecondTable.) The optimizer will use whatever indexes it thinks will be useful. You should probably have an index on every column used in a join or in a WHERE clause. Sometimes, creating one index on a pair of columns is better that one index on each of two columns.